# How is called the class of functions whose inverse function is a polynomial?

Tags: functions, polynomials

How is called the class of functions whose inverse function is a polynomial? Is there any study of such functions?

Comment: Algebraic functions. Although algebraic can be more than just inverses, but implicit functions defined by polynomial equations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function

Comment: Every polynomial is a function, but not every polynomial has an inverse function.

Comment: @hardmath In the same way that saying a "polynomial is a function" is not strictly correct (one must specify a domain an a codomain to give a function) one can talk about inverses of functions without inverses by restricting the domain when necessary. Why be picky if you are also going to use loose terminology?

Comment: @Karene I doubt that inverse to any algebraic function is a polynomial.

Comment: @Anixx Your doubt is correct. As I said already, algebraic functions are functions defined by polynomial equations (implicit function defined). Being inverse is a particular case of implicitly define function.

Comment: @Karene: I'm not sure if you took my comment as a criticism of yours.  It wasn't, and I upvoted your suggested "algebraic functions" even before you pointed out the broadened nature of the category.  Rather my point has to do with whether a narrowed interpretation ("being picky") of Anixx's Question was germane:  should we ask for functions with a global polynomial inverse? (This amounts to a monotone restriction.)  Or if a local polynomial inverse is admitted, would piecewise polynomial inverses be admitted?

Answer (score 1):

The functions you're interested in are a particular subset of the algebraic functions.  To be specific, an algebraic function $f(x)$ is a function that satisfies
$$
a_n(x)f(x)^n+a_{n-1}(x)f(x)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0(x)=0
$$
where the $a_i(x)$ are polynomials.  By contrast, let $$P(x)=b_n x^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + b_0$$ be an arbitrary polynomial.  Its inverse, $P^{-1}(x)$, satisfies
$$
P(P^{-1}(x))=b_nP^{-1}(x)^n+b_{n-1}P^{-1}(x)^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0=x.
$$
So inverses of polynomials are those algebraic functions for which the defining coefficient functions $a_i$ are constants, except for the last, which is a constant minus $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless we want a restriction that the inverse be "globally" a polynomial, i.e. the inverse of a monotone polynomial to ensure the requirement of being a function, the phrase "inverse polynomial" will probably convey the intended class of functions well enough.

Interpolation by inverse polynomials, esp. [inverse quadratic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_quadratic_interpolation), has been studied in connection with [root-finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Inverse_interpolation) and line searches in [optimization](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a095022.pdf).

For degree 1 the inverse polynomial doesn't yield any new methods.  For degree 2 the inverse (quadratic) polynomial has found a popular niche in [Brent's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method).